# PHP array not getting converted into JSON format in online JSON editor

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I've following PHP array after printing it with `print_r()` with me:

```
Array
(

    [title] => Atle
    [code] => ATL
    [classroom] => traditional
    [start_time] => 06:00 AM
    [end_time] => 08:00 AM
    [grp_day] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
            [1] => Fri
            [2] => Sat
        )

    [term] => winter    
)
```

I want this array into valid equivalent JSON format. So I go to the URL `https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/`, on left side I pasted above array as it is and clicked on arrow button to convert it into JSON format but I got error. Can someone please correct the mistake I'm making in the conversion?

I don't want code for this conversion. I want some tool which will convert the PHP array in JSON format.

Thanks.

I received following error :

```
Error: Parse error on line 3:
    [title] => Atle    [
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: what error are u getting..

Comment: @BushraShahid : I got this error:
Error: Parse error on line 3:
    [title] => Atle    [
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']', got 'undefined'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the usage of some 3rd party online tool, not a generally applicable programming question. Contact the author of that site for support. You also seem to be misunderstanding what that tool does.

Comment: Thwn why don't you try [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function of php instead of using conversion tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To receive json from array just use `json_encode($array);`.

And `print_r()` shows incorrect array, use better `var_export()`, because:

```
<?php

$a = [
    1 => 'foo',
    2 => ['bar'],
];

var_dump($a);
/* WILL OUTPUTS:
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
}
*/
print_r($a);
/* WILL OUTPUTS:
Array
(
    [1] => foo
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
        )

)
*/
var_export($a);
/* WILL OUTPUTS:
array (
  1 => 'foo',
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'bar',
  ),
)
*/
```

and now you can copy this output and reuse it, because it's **valid** php array.

And i doubt that http://jsoneditoronline.org/ converts php array to json... because on main page example that convert json to js object, and i found nothing about php arrays...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $arr=Array
        (
            "title" => "Atle",
            "code" => "ATL",
            "classroom" => "traditional",
            "start_time" => "06:00 AM",
            "end_time" => "08:00 AM",
            "grp_day" => Array
                (
                    0 => "Mon",
                    1 => "Fri",
                    2 => "Sat"
                ),

            "term" => "winter"    
        );
    $jsn= json_encode($arr);

echo $jsn;
```

The output will be

```
{"title":"Atle","code":"ATL","classroom":"traditional","start_time":"06:00 AM","end_time":"08:00 AM","grp_day":["Mon","Fri","Sat"],"term":"winter"}
```

[image]

Comment: get that array in a variable then encode it with json .. i used the array which is defined in question and this is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo json_encode($array); instead of print_r as you need valid json for that editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid json to view in [jsoneditoronline](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

To convert the array to json use `json_encode($array)`